# Collect based on Filter of another database - Power Apps

Tags: database, collections, powerapps

I need to simply create a new collection based on data that is filtered by ID from another database.

I figured this code here would work:
ClearCollect(copiedData, Filter(pdarelease_line, releaseID = releaseSelection.Selected.releaseID))

However, after running, the new collection seems to leave out some data.

[image]

Additionally, I am certain data exists in the table I am filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You can make collections of collections or directly from filtering the data source directly. Something like this could work.

```
ClearCollect(
 colCopiedData, 
  Filter(
    MasterDataSourceOrCollectionToFilter, 
    releaseID in colOrDataSourceOfSecondaryFilteredList.ID
  )
);
```

Hope this helps.